# Improve HTML Image Gallery Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, packery

Currently, I'm building a photo gallery for my website using basic Packery JS and Div blocks with images inside of them.

```js
<script>
   var $container = $('#content');
// init
$container.packery({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  gutter: 10,
});
   </script>
```

```html
<div class="item" style="width: 388px; height: 259px;">
  <img src="Resources/images/IMG_8441 - Version 2.jpg" height="259px" width="388px" alt="Intersect" />
</div>
```

Everything is packing pretty well, but scrolling from the top of the page to the bottom isn't really very smooth, presumably due to the sheer number of images on the page (35 as of now). Is there any method to improve the smoothness of the scrolling?

Comment: Are your images big in size (as in mb sizes) instead of optimized for web?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Photoshop?  You need to resave your images via "Save for Web".  This allows you to cut down image size considerably depending on the settings you choose.  This can help improve speed.  Another option is to increase the complexity of your javascript and throw in thumbnails in place of the full scale images.  Once again you could use Photoshop or another image editing software and shrink the image size down to 259 by 388px's.  When you save them resized like this the file size will be considerably smaller.  When a user clicks on the thumbnail image javascript can be used to display the full-scale larger image.

Comment: Already attempted shrinking the images down, but they become far too low resolution to be useable. As far as lightboxing is concerned, I was already planning on doing that, but I can't begin to think about it when my images are highly pixelated. @John23

Comment: What is the typical size of one of your images?  Are you working with photoshop?

Comment: I just did this with a photography website.  I resized all of the images to thumbnail size and used those for display (this took the image sizes from 10-15MB to 15KB...they don't look pixelated).  When the user clicks a thumbnail the HD full-size version of the image pops up.

Comment: Images start any where from 10 to over 20 mb... I've gotten them down to ~1.5 each without any problems in Photoshop cs6.

Comment: If you turn those into thumbnails they'll get down to around 10-20kb.  I think my thumbnails are around 300 pixels wide.